# Passing table values from template to view

Tags: python, html, django

I have template with table which is dynamically created by javascript. Then I want retrieve with submit button only value within `<td name="plu"></td>` tags and process it in view to save as json into CharField in model. I tried to use form tag with method post and `request.POST.get('plu')` in view but it won't work. I want to get that values and then process it with model methods.
Here are parts of code:

```
@login_required()
def cash_register(request):

    """plus = [123,345,567]
    newtrans = Transaction()
    newtrans.set_plu_list(plus)
    newtrans.save()"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.POST.get('plu', False)
        # ???


    try:
        products = Product.objects.all().values_list('plu_num', 'art_name', 'sales_price_brutto')
        products_json = json.dumps(list(products), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Products cant\'t be found!')

    return render(request, 'panel/cash_register.html', {'products_json': products_json})


class Transaction(models.Model):

    plu_list = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    transaction_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_ksk = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ksk_num = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def set_plu_list(self, x):
        self.plu_list = json.dumps(x)

    def get_plu_list(self):
        return json.loads(self.plu_list)
```

And html: https://pastebin.com/RFn5qNn2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a thing you can do. `<td>` elements are not form fields; you can't "submit" them.

If you want values to be submitted to the backend, you either have to use actual form inputs, or use Ajax to send the data.

Comment: Got it by creating new hidden input with my javascript function and then getting it, I appreciate your explanation, thanks.